# An isomorphism $f:G_1 \to G_2$ maps the identity of $G_1$ to the identity of $G_2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, alternative-proof

Here is my attempted proof:

Suppose $e_1$ is the identity of $G_1$ and likewise $e_2$ is the identity of $G_2$. Then we have to show $f(e_1)=e_2$.

Since $f$ is an isomorphism, $f$ is bijective and hence surjective. Therefore, $f(x)=e_2$ for some $x\in G_1$.

Also, $f(x\cdot e_1)=e_2$. This implies $f(x)f(e_1)=e_2$. Also the product of $f(x)$ and $f(e_1)$ gives the identity, hence they must be inverses of each other, i.e. $f(e_1)=f(x)^{-1}$. But $f(x)=e_2$ and hence $f(e_1)=e_{2}^{-1}=e_2$.

Is my proof correct? Are there any alternative ways?

Comment: $\{f(x)\}^{-1}$ looks like a set...just use $f(x)^{-1}$. It is clear what this means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is correct, but you are explicitly using surjectivity. You don't actually need this, but instead all you need is for the map $f$ to be a homomorphism (so not necessarily a surjective or injective):

> If $f: G_1\rightarrow G_2$ is a group homomorphism then $f(e_1)=e_2$.

*Proof.* Write $g:=f(e_1)$. Then $g^2=f(e_1)^2=f(e_1^2)=f(e_1)=g$. That is, $g^2=g$. Then:
$$\begin{align*}
g^2&=g\\
\Rightarrow
g^2\cdot g^{-1}&=g\cdot g^{-1}\\
\Rightarrow
g&=e_2
\end{align*}$$
Therefore, $f(e_1)=e_2$ as required.

Comment: I'm yet to learn homomorphism. However, is my proof correct?

Comment: I've edited my post to comment on your answer. A homomorphism is a map $f$ such that $f(xy)=f(x)f(y)$. You've used the fact that your map is a homomorphism when you said $f(x\cdot e_1)=f(x)f(e_1)$. The fact that you are trying to prove does *not* hold for bijections which are not homomorphisms. For example, consider the integers under addition. Then adding $1$ to each integer defines an isomorphism, but the identity $0$ is mapped to $1$, a non-identity element... [Alternatively, swap the two elements in the group of order two. This is a bijection, but the identity is not mapped to itself.]

Comment: My textbook defines isomorphism as such: A bijective function $f:G_1\to G_2$ with the property that for any two elements $a,b\in G_1$, $f(ab)=f(a)f(b)$ is called an isomorphism from $G_1$ to $G_2$.

Comment: I understand your example and if I understand it properly what you're basically trying to say is isomorphism is basically a special case of homomorphism. Am i right?

Comment: @AshishKujur That's correct. An isomorphism can be defined as a bijective homomorphism.

Comment: Well I'm self studying Abstract Algebra now and I need a little more help. My textbook (Pinter's Abstract Algebra) states that homomorphisms are surjections. So, does my proof for isomorphism still hold for a homomorphism even though it's an overkill?

Comment: @AshishKujur Homomorphisms are *not* surjective in general. There is a special name for surjective homomorphisms: epimorphisms. Similarly, monomorphisms are injective homomorphisms and isomorphisms are bijective isomorphisms.

Comment: (is this Pinter's book "A Book of Abstract Algebra"? This book defines a homomorphism, then says "If there exists a homomorphism from $G$ onto $H$, we say that $H$ is a homomorphic image of $G$". Maybe this is where your confusion lies - homomorphisms are not surjective in general, but if a given homomorphism is surjective then we give the image group a fancy name...)

Comment: @user1729 Ah, I read it wrong. Thanks again! :)